# Multiline Radiobutton

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've radio buttuons in my WP-8 application.

All contents of my radiobuttons are overlapping. I've fixed height and width but words are not wrapping to second line. How can I solve this problem?

Please do not say something like "\n" content is dynamic.

Comment: Can you give some example code what you've got so far (and perhaps a screenshot)?

Comment: radiobutton.content=array[0]; this is it. just write something into a radio button. it's always single-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably setting text to `Content` property as a string. But you can also use `TextBlock`.

XAML

```xml
<RadioButton>
    <TextBlock Text="This is very long text that I want to wrap. Is it long enough?" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</RadioButton>
```

C#

```cs
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.Content = new TextBlock()
{
    Text = "This is very long text that I want to wrap. Is it long enough?",
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
};
```

Result
[image: screenshot]